# What's the most efficient way of operating with fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, math, operations

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DATE(utimestamp) as utimestamp, name, data*2000000 from tData 
where utimestamp BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-16 00:00:00' 
AND name = 'Valor2' and data>20
group by YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp), name 
union
SELECT DATE(utimestamp) as utimestamp, name, data*0.1 from tData 
where utimestamp BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-16 00:00:00' 
AND name = 'Valor1' and data>20 
group by YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp), name 
order by utimestamp asc
```

Is there a more efficient way of operating with 'data'? Is there a way of doing this without using **UNION**?

Comment: You might wanna check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks @JeffPuckettII, it's a very interesting contribution, this question belongs more there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `case when then`:

```
SELECT DATE(utimestamp) as utimestamp, name, 
case when name = 'Valor1' then data*0.1
     when name = 'Valor2' then data*2000000 
end
from tData 
where utimestamp BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-16 00:00:00' 
and data>20 
group by YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp), name 
order by utimestamp asc
```

Comment: Is there a way of naming the resulting data from the case-end? I'm getting that column as 'case when name_collector_noname = 'Valor1' then data*0.1  when name_collector_noname = 'Valor2' then data*2000000 end'. I've tried 'as value' at the end but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The query in your question is strange, because it has a math calculation without an aggregation function.  And, you are aggregating by year and month, but not including them in the query.

I would be inclined to put the values in two separate columns, with the year and month explicitly defined in the query:

```
select year(utimestamp), month(utimestamp),
       sum(case when name = 'Valor1' then data*0.01 end) as valor1,
       sum(case when name = 'Valor2' then data*2000000 end) as valor2
from tData 
where utimestamp between '2016-01-01' and '2016-04-16' and
      name in ('Valor1', 'Valor2') and 
      data > 20
group by year(utimestamp), month(utimestamp)
order by max(utimestamp);
```